# Excel: Data validation settings change & Apply these changes to all other cells with same settings

Tags: excel

When changing the data validation settings for a cell, there is a checkbox that allows you to apply the change to all cells with the same data validation setting. However, this doesn't seem to produce satisfactory results. I have a worksheet with a bunch of cells in the same column, having the same data validation setting - which I want to change. There are several such groups of cells in the same column, each separated by a few rows that contain other stuff (headers, etc). When I do the "apply these changes...", only one group is selected and changed, not all the items in the whole column or worksheet.

For example, in column A:
A1 to A5: Same data validation setting

A6 to A8: Other stuff

A9 to A14: Same data validation setting (as in A1 to A5)

A15 to A18: Other stuff

A19 to A23: Same data validation setting

When I select A1 and change the data val setting & hit the checkbox for "apply these changes...", it changes A1 to A5, but not A9 to A14 or A19 to A23. I can't possibly repeat this procedure for each group of cells - there are too many. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Please try selecting a cell with an example of the validation rule you want to change, HOME > Editing, - Find & Select, Go To Special..., Data validation, check Same. Set the rule for the active cell, check *Apply these changes to all other cells with the same settings*, OK.

Comment: Works, thank you. When you select multiple cells & hit data validation, it warns that it will clear the settings (this doesn't happen when a single cell is selected). However, if you choose to proceed, it works out fine.